# Catching ActiveX Control's Events

Tags: mfc, activex

I've created an MFC ActiveX control in VS2008.  My controls class is as follows:

Header File:

```
#pragma once
#include "Background_Dialog.h"

// Dual_Color_TrackbarCtrl.h : Declaration of the CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl ActiveX Control class.


// CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl : See Dual_Color_TrackbarCtrl.cpp for implementation.

class CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl : public COleControl
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl)
    friend class Background_Dialog;

    // Constructor
    public:
     CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl();

    // Overrides
    public:
     virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pdc, const CRect& rcBounds, const CRect& rcInvalid);
     virtual void DoPropExchange(CPropExchange* pPX);
     virtual void OnResetState();
     virtual DWORD GetControlFlags();

     Background_Dialog m_View;

// Implementation
protected:
   ~CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl();

    DECLARE_OLECREATE_EX(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl)    // Class factory and guid
    DECLARE_OLETYPELIB(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl)      // GetTypeInfo
    DECLARE_PROPPAGEIDS(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl)     // Property page IDs
    DECLARE_OLECTLTYPE(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl)        // Type name and misc status

// Message maps
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Dispatch maps
DECLARE_DISPATCH_MAP()

// Event maps
DECLARE_EVENT_MAP()

// Dispatch and event IDs
public:
enum {
    eventidTestEvent = 1L,
    dispidGetHighValue = 6L,
    dispidGetLowValue = 5L,
    dispidSetColor = 4L,
    dispidSetLowValueText = 3L,
    dispidSetHighValueText = 2L,
    dispidSetRange = 1L
};
protected:
    void SetRange(LONG low, LONG high);
    void SetHighValueText(CHAR* str);
    void SetLowValueText(CHAR* str);
    void SetColor(ULONG color);
    DOUBLE GetLowValue(void);
    DOUBLE GetHighValue(void);


public:
afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
void SendEvent(void);
void TestEvent(void)
{
    FireEvent(eventidTestEvent, EVENT_PARAM(VTS_NONE));
}
};
```

.cpp file:

```
// Dual_Color_TrackbarCtrl.cpp : Implementation of the CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl ActiveX Control class.

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Dual_Color_Trackbar.h"
    #include "Dual_Color_TrackbarCtrl.h"
    #include "Dual_Color_TrackbarPropPage.h"


    #ifdef _DEBUG
    #define new DEBUG_NEW
    #endif


    IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, COleControl)



    // Message map

    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, COleControl)
        ON_OLEVERB(AFX_IDS_VERB_PROPERTIES, OnProperties)
        ON_WM_CREATE()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()



    // Dispatch map

    BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, COleControl)
        DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, "SetRange", dispidSetRange, SetRange, VT_EMPTY, VTS_I4 VTS_I4)
        DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, "SetHighValueText", dispidSetHighValueText, SetHighValueText, VT_EMPTY, VTS_PI1)
        DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, "SetLowValueText", dispidSetLowValueText, SetLowValueText, VT_EMPTY, VTS_PI1)
        DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, "SetColor", dispidSetColor, SetColor, VT_EMPTY, VTS_UI4)
        DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, "GetLowValue", dispidGetLowValue, GetLowValue, VT_R8, VTS_NONE)
        DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, "GetHighValue", dispidGetHighValue, GetHighValue, VT_R8, VTS_NONE)
    END_DISPATCH_MAP()



    // Event map

    BEGIN_EVENT_MAP(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, COleControl)
        EVENT_CUSTOM_ID("TestEvent", eventidTestEvent, TestEvent, VTS_NONE)
    END_EVENT_MAP()



    // Property pages

    // TODO: Add more property pages as needed.  Remember to increase the count!
    BEGIN_PROPPAGEIDS(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, 1)
        PROPPAGEID(CDual_Color_TrackbarPropPage::guid)
    END_PROPPAGEIDS(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl)



    // Initialize class factory and guid

    IMPLEMENT_OLECREATE_EX(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, "DUAL_COLOR_TRACK.Dual_Color_TrackCtrl.1",
        0x14e49ebd, 0x62e0, 0x496e, 0x86, 0xc, 0xe, 0x1a, 0xea, 0xca, 0x86, 0xf3)



    // Type library ID and version

    IMPLEMENT_OLETYPELIB(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, _tlid, _wVerMajor, _wVerMinor)



    // Interface IDs

    const IID BASED_CODE IID_DDual_Color_Trackbar =
            { 0xA0566CF1, 0x2C81, 0x4295, { 0xAF, 0x52, 0xD7, 0x26, 0x9E, 0x90, 0x7F, 0xA3 } };
    const IID BASED_CODE IID_DDual_Color_TrackbarEvents =
            { 0xA1916D8D, 0x9135, 0x41D8, { 0x8C, 0x82, 0x42, 0x21, 0x75, 0xE0, 0xD7, 0x2F } };



    // Control type information

    static const DWORD BASED_CODE _dwDual_Color_TrackbarOleMisc =
        OLEMISC_ACTIVATEWHENVISIBLE |
        OLEMISC_SETCLIENTSITEFIRST |
        OLEMISC_INSIDEOUT |
        OLEMISC_CANTLINKINSIDE |
        OLEMISC_RECOMPOSEONRESIZE;

    IMPLEMENT_OLECTLTYPE(CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl, IDS_DUAL_COLOR_TRACKBAR, _dwDual_Color_TrackbarOleMisc)



    // CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrlFactory::UpdateRegistry -
    // Adds or removes system registry entries for CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl

    BOOL CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrlFactory::UpdateRegistry(BOOL bRegister)
    {
        // TODO: Verify that your control follows apartment-model threading rules.
        // Refer to MFC TechNote 64 for more information.
        // If your control does not conform to the apartment-model rules, then
        // you must modify the code below, changing the 6th parameter from
        // afxRegApartmentThreading to 0.

        if (bRegister)
            return AfxOleRegisterControlClass(
                AfxGetInstanceHandle(),
                m_clsid,
                m_lpszProgID,
                IDS_DUAL_COLOR_TRACKBAR,
                IDB_DUAL_COLOR_TRACKBAR,
                afxRegApartmentThreading,
                _dwDual_Color_TrackbarOleMisc,
                _tlid,
                _wVerMajor,
                _wVerMinor);
        else
            return AfxOleUnregisterClass(m_clsid, m_lpszProgID);
    }



    // CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl - Constructor

    CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl()
    {
        InitializeIIDs(&IID_DDual_Color_Trackbar, &IID_DDual_Color_TrackbarEvents);
        // TODO: Initialize your control's instance data here.
    }



    // CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::~CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl - Destructor

    CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::~CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl()
    {
        // TODO: Cleanup your control's instance data here.
    }



    // CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::OnDraw - Drawing function

    void CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::OnDraw(
                CDC* pdc, const CRect& rcBounds, const CRect& rcInvalid)
    {
        if (!pdc)
            return;

        m_View.MoveWindow(rcBounds);
        CBrush bkgndColor(TranslateColor(AmbientBackColor()));
        FillRect(*pdc,rcBounds,bkgndColor);
        DeleteObject(bkgndColor);
    }



    // CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::DoPropExchange - Persistence support

    void CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::DoPropExchange(CPropExchange* pPX)
    {
        ExchangeVersion(pPX, MAKELONG(_wVerMinor, _wVerMajor));
        COleControl::DoPropExchange(pPX);

        // TODO: Call PX_ functions for each persistent custom property.
    }



    // CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::GetControlFlags -
    // Flags to customize MFC's implementation of ActiveX controls.
    //
    DWORD CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::GetControlFlags()
    {
        DWORD dwFlags = COleControl::GetControlFlags();

        return dwFlags;
    }



    // CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::OnResetState - Reset control to default state

    void CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::OnResetState()
    {
        COleControl::OnResetState();  // Resets defaults found in DoPropExchange

        // TODO: Reset any other control state here.
    }



    // CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl message handlers




    void CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::SetRange(LONG low, LONG high)
    {
        AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

        // TODO: Add your dispatch handler code here
    }

    void CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::SetHighValueText(CHAR* str)
    {
        AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

        // TODO: Add your dispatch handler code here
    }

    void CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::SetLowValueText(CHAR* str)
    {
        AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

        // TODO: Add your dispatch handler code here
    }

    void CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::SetColor(ULONG color)
    {
        AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

        // TODO: Add your dispatch handler code here
    }

    DOUBLE CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::GetLowValue(void)
    {
        AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

        // TODO: Add your dispatch handler code here

        return 0;
    }

    DOUBLE CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::GetHighValue(void)
    {
        AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

        // TODO: Add your dispatch handler code here

        return 0;
    }

    int CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
    {
        if (COleControl::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
            return -1;

        m_View.Create(IDD_BACKGROUND,this);

        return 0;
    }

    void CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl::SendEvent(void)
    {
        this->TestEvent();
    }
```

.idl file

```
        // Dual_Color_Trackbar.idl : type library source for ActiveX Control project.

        // This file will be processed by the MIDL compiler tool to
        // produce the type library (Dual_Color_Trackbar.tlb) that will become a resource in
        // Dual_Color_Trackbar.ocx.

        #include <olectl.h>
        #include <idispids.h>

        [ uuid(96F872A0-1522-4A93-97E1-CFF4BE483A65), version(1.0),
          helpfile("Dual_Color_Trackbar.hlp"),
          helpstring("Dual_Color_Trackbar ActiveX Control module"),
          control ]
        library Dual_Color_TrackbarLib
        {
            importlib(STDOLE_TLB);

            //  Primary dispatch interface for CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl

            [ uuid(A0566CF1-2C81-4295-AF52-D7269E907FA3),
              helpstring("Dispatch interface for Dual_Color_Trackbar Control")]
            dispinterface _DDual_Color_Trackbar
            {
                properties:
                methods:
                    [id(1), helpstring("Sets the bounds of the Trackbar")] void SetRange(LONG low, LONG high);
                    [id(2), helpstring("Sets the string of the high edit control")] void SetHighValueText(CHAR* str);
                    [id(3), helpstring("Sets the string of the low value edit box.")] void SetLowValueText(CHAR* str);
                    [id(4), helpstring("Sets the color of the trackbar")] void SetColor(ULONG color);
                    [id(5), helpstring("Get the low value of the trackbar")] DOUBLE GetLowValue(void);
                    [id(6), helpstring("Gets the high value of the trackbar")] DOUBLE GetHighValue(void);
            };

            //  Event dispatch interface for CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl

            [ uuid(A1916D8D-9135-41D8-8C82-422175E0D72F),
              helpstring("Event interface for Dual_Color_Trackbar Control") ]
            dispinterface _DDual_Color_TrackbarEvents
            {
                properties:
                    //  Event interface has no properties

                methods:
                    [id(1)] void TestEvent(void);
            };

            //  Class information for CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl

            [ uuid(14E49EBD-62E0-496E-860C-0E1AEACA86F3),
              helpstring("Dual_Color_Trackbar Control"), control ]
            coclass Dual_Color_Trackbar
            {
                [default] dispinterface _DDual_Color_Trackbar;
                [default, source] dispinterface _DDual_Color_TrackbarEvents;
            };

        };
```

I fire my event using the statement:

```
 CDual_Color_TrackbarCtrl ds;

 ds.SendEvent();
```

in a friend class of the control.

In the client dialog box that I am placing the control I sink my event but the handler function is never getting called.  Am I missing something in the control's implementation?  What steps do I need to take in the client dialog application to make sure the event can be captured?